# You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a SQL trigger which after updating the table will execute a piece of SQl to update it again

I have 5 fields that can be updated that each contain 0 or 1:

> *step1_complete, step2_complete, step3_complete, step4_complete* and *step5_complete*

after any of these columns are updated I want to run a trigger that will update *percent_complete* within the same table with the following query:

```
SELECT sum( step1_complete + 
            step2_complete + 
            step3_complete + 
            step4_complete + 
            step5_complete ) * 20 AS Sum 
FROM completed_part 
GROUP BY id
```

this query will return either 20, 40, 60, 80 or 100 which is what i expect but when i try to run the update query to see if it works i get this error message

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'completed_part' for update in
>   FROM clause

I would also like to know if this is the correct syntax for creating a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `completed_part_after_update` AFTER UPDATE 
    ON `completed_part` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        UPDATE completed_part 
        SET percent_complete = (
            SELECT sum( step1_complete +
                        step2_complete +
                        step3_complete +
                        step4_complete + 
                        step5_complete ) * 20 AS Sum
        FROM completed_part 
        GROUP BY id
        );

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: One thing I see is you're trying to update a field `percent_complete` with a subquery that returns two fields.

Comment: You cannot directly do an update of a table based on a sub query on the same table.

Comment: You can't update the same table. You created an AFTER UPDATE trigger which UPDATEs the same table. That would create an infinite loop. It's prohibited because of that.

Comment: Ah...i see. That makes sense. I need to rethink my table structures then

Comment: Well.. we were all quick to tell you what's wrong, but not what you can do :) you can have a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, and in that trigger you can perform the calculation and set your `percent_complete` value. However, I am writing this after a long day so as always, question everything (your table structure, my comment etc.) until the pieces click together.

Comment: If you check #1093 in this link there is a description - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html . There are methods to bypass this with normal updates, but @N.B. is correct the you also risk an infinite loop if you manage to get this to work. Further point is that your sub query returns multiple rows (one for each id), which you can't use to update a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use **BEFOR UPDATE**

```
BEGIN

SET NEW.percent_complete = ( NEW.step1_complete + NEW.step2_complete + NEW.step3_complete + NEW.step4_complete + NEW.step5_complete ) * 20;

END
```

Comment: Just what I was trying to do