# MySQL Triggers: Using a conditional statement

Tags: mysql, triggers, conditional-statements

I have a trigger which i finally got working in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891589/you-cant-specify-target-table-my-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

What I would like to do now is, in the same trigger, if a specific field changes, update a specific field. So when *step5_complete* is changed from 0 to 1, I want to update the *date_completed* field to the current datetime.

I currently get an error message about error in SQL syntax but it says

> near '//' at line 13

which is

```
SET NEW.percent_complete = ( NEW.step1_complete + NEW.step2_complete + NEW.step3_complete + NEW.step4_complete + NEW.step5_complete ) * 20;
```

Here is my complete trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS completed_part_after_update ;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER completed_part_after_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON completed_part FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  IF NEW.step5_complete <> OLD.step5_complete THEN
     SET NEW.date_completed = NOW();     
  END IF;

  SET NEW.percent_complete = ( NEW.step1_complete + NEW.step2_complete + NEW.step3_complete + NEW.step4_complete + NEW.step5_complete ) * 20;

END; //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement is looks wrong. It should be

```
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

That is, trigger body should look like

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER completed_part_after_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON completed_part FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  IF NEW.step5_complete <> OLD.step5_complete THEN
     SET NEW.date_completed = NOW();     
  END IF;

  SET NEW.percent_complete = ( NEW.step1_complete + NEW.step2_complete + NEW.step3_complete + NEW.step4_complete + NEW.step5_complete ) * 20;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```